# SAT scores program in Python?

Tags: python

Okay, so here is what I've been charged with:

Write a function, applyToCollege (with parameters reading, math, writing), that determines whether the user’s SAT test scores will be enough to be admitted to a college.

The user will enter the test scores: Critical Reading, Mathematics, and Writing (in this
order). If the scores are in the following ranges (inclusively) and the total score is also on its range (inclusively) the student must be admitted: Critical Reading (680-800), Mathematics (690-800), Writing (650-800), and Total: (2060-2400).

Let the student know if he or she has been admitted or not to
the school. If admitted return the string “Congratulations, you have been admitted!”, otherwise return the string “I’m sorry to inform you we cannot offer you admission”. You may assume the user will only enter positive integers, but let the user know if he/she entered invalid scores above the 800 point maximum. (scores > 800 are invalid scores).

I've combed my course readings that have so far been assigned but I don't even know where to begin. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you done anything in your course on flow control, specifically [`if`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) statements?

Comment: We have done if statements, but I don't know how to use them in the context of this assignment.

Comment: The Q&A format here requires that you ask a question about a specific problem you're having with code. It seems like you're looking for advice but the site only works with questions that have a "correct" answer or rather, questions where answers won't be subjective or where all answers could be correct.

Comment: Some concerns need to be directed to your course instructor. "I don't know where to start." Is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a series of if statements like this.

if critical_reading<680 :
  ##Deal with result

You can also have a variable that is the sum of all the scores

Total = critical_reading + math + writing